# Is chirality absolute or relative?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality

While going through some questions on chirality and optical isomerism, I came across this compound:

[image: Compound]

Note that I have marked 3 carbons as $C_1,C_2,C_3$

Its obvious that $C_1,C_3$ are chiral carbons.

$C_2$ is not a chiral carbon as it has the same group above and below it( With respect to the picture)

However a thought struck me that chiral carbon meant that 4 different groups are attached to it.

But what exactly does *same* group mean?

Does it mean that even the spatial arrangement of the groups should be different?

Or does it not matter?

So if spatial arrangement mattered, then the compound I have mentioned would have a chiral $C_2$ carbon for specific configurations around $C_1$ and $C_3$ carbons.

Comment: C1 and C3 are chiral atoms, and are of the variety R or S. As a consequence, RR and SS are optically active. But the combinations RS and SR are optically inactive. They are meso compounds.

Comment: Even in the meso compound, C2 is pseudochiral.

Comment: C2 is achirotopic but stereogenic with a configuration of r (lower case).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, spatial configuration of attached groups matters. Meaning different stereo configuration of $C_1$ and $C_3$ may render $C_2$ either chiral or not:

[image]

Also because you have more than 1 stereo center you're not limited to just enantiomers, you can get diastereomers - the molecules will be different even though they're not mirror images of each other:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The compound must pass the sigma test, as in symmetry. If you imagine a mirror cross sectioning the molecule with more than one chiral carbon and the substituents of the chiral centers are cis, then the molecule is achiral. If the substituents are in a trans configuration, then the molecule is chiral.

Comment: Don't we use R and S for this instead of cis and trans? Thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: R and S are to designate what direction the substituents of the enantiomers rotate in respect to the chiral center. Cis and Trans are used for denoting whether a compound with two or more chiral centers is chiral or not.